# Laravel: use blade template in javascript

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.3 for my application. On a form, I am trying to make ajax call from javascript.

The [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) show how to give a static `url` for the ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

I know I can substitute the `test.html` with any URI from my `routes.php` file. But I don't want it to be static. It would be better if I can call a Controller function. This will allow me to change the URI in future without changing the code.

In short, I need a way to call the `action()` function of Laravel in the javascript. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple.

Just do this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: {{ action('ControllerClass@functionName', [parameter_list]) }},
  context: document.body
}).done(function() {
  $( this ).addClass( "done" );
});
```

Let the **blade** engine handle the rest of the task.